# two tangents of two parabolas meet at right angle.

Tags: geometry, tangent-line

Two straight line are at right angles to one another, one of them touches the parabola $y^2=4a(x+a)$ and the other touches the parabola $y^2=4a'(x+a')$. Show that the point of intersection of the straight lines will lie on the straight line $x+a+a'=0$.

I tried to solve this problem, I find two tangents of two parabolas, then they meet at right angle,$(m_1.m_2=-1)$. But I can not find the result. Someone  please help.

Comment: You say you found two tangents of the two parabolas. What exactly did you find? Did you find an equation for each tangent line? I recommend you edit the question to include all the details of the work you have done.

Comment: actually i find two tangents at $P(x_1, y_1)$ on 1st parabola and then $Q(x_2, y_2)$ on the second parabola

Comment: Do you understand the difference between what I recommended and what you did in your last comment? I still don't see any equations that you have written except for the three equations that were given to you in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=mx+c$ be tangent to the curve $y^2=4a(x+a)$

Solving simultaneously gives the quadratic $$m^2x^2+x(2mc-4a)+c^2-4a^2=0$$

This has zero discriminant as a condition for tangency, so after a couple of lines of algebra, we get $$\frac{m}{1+m^
2}=\frac ac$$

Now let the perpendicular line have equation $y=-\frac 1m x+c'$ which is tangent to the curve $y^2=4a'(x+a')$

In which case, without further calculation, we have $$\frac{-\frac 1m}{1+\frac{1}{m^2}}=\frac{a'}{c'}$$

Therefore, $$\frac{m}{1+m^
2}=\frac ac=-\frac {a'}{c'}$$

Meanwhile, solving the two lines simultaneously gives $$x=\frac{m}{m^2+1}(c'-c)$$

So, using the above results, the locus is $$x=-a'-a$$ as required.